# canvas.toDataURL() returns a blank image on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, html5-canvas, mobile-safari

The implementation works on computer but does not work on iOS devices (tested on simulator).

I wrote the following function. Aware of size limitations on iOS, there is first a conversion to create a smaller canvas from the bigger one (without the conversion `.toDataURL()` returns `data:,`), the issue is that the returned data url corresponds to a blank image with the desired sizes. I have tried awaiting seconds after calling the `drawImage` method but had no success. Is it still related to memory capacity? Am I missing a step on canvas conversion?

The code:

```
export const pdfToImage = async (pdfData: Buffer): Promise<pngData[] | undefined> => {
  return await new Promise(resolve => {
    const node = document.createElement('div')
    const body = document.querySelector('body')
    if (!body) {
      resolve(undefined)
      return
    }
    body.append(node)

    const onAllPagesrendered = async () => {
      const pngs: pngData[] = []

      const canvases = node.querySelectorAll('canvas')

      for (const canvas of canvases) {
        const maxSize = 1200
        const maxDimension =
          canvas.width > canvas.height ? ('width' as const) : ('height' as const)
        let newWidth = canvas.width
        let newHeight = canvas.height
        if (maxDimension === 'width' && canvas.width > maxSize) {
          newWidth = maxSize
          newHeight = (canvas.height / canvas.width) * maxSize
        } else if (maxDimension === 'height' && canvas.height > maxSize) {
          newHeight = maxSize
          newWidth = (canvas.width / canvas.height) * maxSize
        }
        const newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas')

        newCanvas.width = newWidth
        newCanvas.height = newHeight

        const ctx = newCanvas.getContext('2d')
        if (ctx) {
          ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)
        }

        pngs.push({
          width: newWidth,
          height: newHeight,
          data: newCanvas.toDataURL('image/png'),
        })
      }
      body.removeChild(node)
      resolve(pngs)
    }
    ReactDOM.render(
      <FullPdfView content={pdfData} onAllPagesRendered={onAllPagesrendered} print />,
      node
    )
  })
}
```

Comment: Any errors in console?  Data URLs can have really small limits, you might be better using blob URLs.